# Combination JQuery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, database

I'm making a project with the slides of text.
I have in the page a main div that contain the text of each slide.
I saved the content in a database.
I want do this operation:
When I click the arrow for view the next slide, PHP catch from database the content and save it in a variable.
Then with JQuery, I replace the maindiv's content with variable.

It is possible? If not, How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into? *If you're a walrus we're going to need pictures. A programming walrus would be worth billions.*

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about making an Ajax request. Do you want to update the information on the page without refreshing? Just by pressing your arrow?

Comment: Check about AJAX request then, this is what you're looking for (and check about Walrus too)

Answer (score 0):

Use a ajax request to simulate a post request, and parse the information with php. You will end up with someting like this:

```
<?php
if( isset( $_POST["slide"]  ) {
  // Database stuff
  // Echo back 
  echo "Information that you need to get in jQuery";
}
?>
<script>
$("button.next_slide").click(function(){
  var ajax;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("some_element").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
    }
  }
  ajax.open("POST","this_page.php?slide=1&foo=bar&bar=foo",true);
  ajax.send();
});
</script>

<button class="next_slide">Next slide</button>
<div id="some_element"></div>
```

**Note:** This could be done without jQuery, or with jQuery's `$.ajax` method. Read more here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, you want to load some data when user click on a particular button and then load it into a div we can achieve it via jQuery ajax and PHP.

**HTML**

```
<div class="main_div">
 <ul id="list"><!-- Our content will load here --></ul>
 <a href="#" class="call_ajax">Next</a>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.call_ajax').on('click', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $.post('ajax.php', { get_slide: true }, function(response){
               // We are telling jQuery to parse response as json because in ajax.php we have used json_encode function. 
                var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                $("#list").append('<li>' + data['slide'] + '</li>');   
          });  
    })
})
```

**PHP ajax.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['get_slide'])){
  //Get slide from db and output it as json, but currently for example purpose we assume that we have a array.

   $data['slide'] = 'Your slide text';
   echo json_encode($data); die(); // We have used die because we don't won't our script to run any more.
}
```

I've not tested it, but it will work.